# Is there a way to improve return time of ref cursor data set?

Tags: function, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, cursor

I have a procedure that builds the where clause of a query based off of the text from a user's input, and a function that concats the query and the where clause and returns a refcursor. This works fine for a small numbers of rows, but if the user were to input wildcards or search on a field that has 100k+ rows, the cursor is slow to return. Is there a better way to do this without a ref cursor, or a way to improve opening the cursor? Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY schema.query_builder
AS
FUNCTION input_cur (search_value_in IN VARCHAR2, search_name_in IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN ref_cursor
IS
refcursor ref_cursor;
whereclause VARCHAR2(2048);

BEGIN
buildwhereclause(search_value_in,search_name_in, whereclause);

OPEN refcursor FOR 'SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, ...COL25                                                       
                FROM   VIEW ' || whereclause;

return refcursor;
END input_cur;
END query_builder;
/
```

Comment: The issue is not in the way you open the cursor but it the fact that, depending on the WHERE condition, the resulting query can be from trivial to very complex. One way could be defining more than 1 view and dynamically switch from one to another, based on the where condition.For example, assuming that the view is based on many tables, are you sure you always need to query them all, or maybe some where condition may not need all the tables in the view? Or maybe you need varying hints, depending on the where condition

Comment: You also need to guard against sql injection, since you are concatenating a bunch of text to your SELECT. A good place to do that is in your buildwhereclause procedure.

Comment: @Aleksej - just to elaborate on your comment about it not being an issue on opening the cursor. There isnt a better way to return multiple rows from function/procedure? Or is it always best practice to return the cursor object to send to the front end application or is it just situational?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Aleksej and @StevenFeurstein. I will definitely consider simplifying the view and eliminating unnecessary columns that may not be needed each time. The view is more of an all encompassing detailed view that is used on the first page before the drill down so maybe splitting them out into two separate ones will help. After creating a 'summary" view, the cursor opened in about 12 minutes for the WHERE building like '99%' clause that returns over 100k+. Definitely better than the 30+ minutes. Any hints you recommend?